# How do use asp web.config variable as link

Tags: asp.net

Hi i'm working on a link inside a asp:login and I want to add a "variable" from the web config instead of hard coding the link directly inside the aspx.

```
 <asp:login
        ID="seamenLogin" runat="server" 
        Inloggning med <a class='linkbutton' href='https:// (BankID, Mobil BankID, ...)</a><br/><br/><br/>
</asp:login>
```

My web.config:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="autoemail" value="someone@somedomain.com" />
  </appSettings>
```

I want the text "someone@somedomain.com" to be a link inside the login aspx.

Does anyone know how to make it so?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help.

1) **web.config:**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="autoemail" value="someone@somedomain.com"/>
  </appSettings>
```

**Aspx page:**

```
 <a href="mailto:<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["autoemail"]%>">Link</a>
```

**Don't forget to add System.Configuration in references.**

Comment: Thank you. 
How would it look like if it was a website link instead of a mail?

Comment: It would be more or less similar. It would be something like <a href="<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["webAddress"]%>">Link</a> when key value in config is like http://google.com

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an old thread, but, perhaps the best way is to code the value directly into the control that you're working with.

The easiest way to do this is to use the configuration specifier code block `<%$ %>`. You see this when you set-up a data connection stored in the connection strings section of your web.config file.

Here's an example based on what you've specified above...

```
<asp:login ID="seamenLogin" runat="server">
    Inloggning med
    <a class='linkbutton' href='<%$ appSettings:autoemail %>'>(BankID, Mobil BankID, ...)</a>
    <br/><br/><br/>
</asp:login>
```

Notice the `href='<%$ appSettings:MyLoginLink %>'`. You're telling the application to lookup the configuration section `appSettings` and the key value `autoemail`.

I realise it's a little late to help you now, but it may help others in the future.