# Change asp:hyperlink navigationurl based on subdomain

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have multiple instances of two sites, DEV, QA, UAT-STAGING, UAT, PROD-STAGING and PROD. I have a login button that need to link to the secure portal.

So when on DEV, the user would go to dev.secure.com, on QA, qa.secure.com, UAT (either one), uat.secure.com, PROD (either one), secure.com.

Here's my code snippet.

```html
           if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("dev."))
            {
                btn_login.NavigateUrl = "https://dev.secure.com";
            }
            else if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("qa."))
            {
                btn_login.NavigateUrl = "https://qa.secure.com";
            }
            else if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("uat"))
            {
                btn_login.NavigateUrl = "https://qa.secure.coma";
            }
            else
            {
                btn_login.NavigateUrl = "https://secure.com";
            }
```

This seems to be working, but is it the best way to do this? I had thought about a rewrite rule in the web.config, but started with this first.

Comment: Most applications I've worked on and created myself, the url is in the web.config. Just change the value according to which server is hosting it.

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296405/how-do-use-asp-web-config-variable-as-link

Comment: Yes. Just remember if you replace the entire web.config file on a server, you need to change that value again. Always good practice to edit the config file rather than replacing the entire file.

Comment: Thanks. I'll get it working on my local and dev enviroment, then document that changes that need to happen to get the build server updated.

Comment: Here's my line of code <asp:HyperLink ID="btn_login" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-login" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl="<%$ AppSettings:btnloginUrl %>" />

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to accomplish this.

The main problem i see in your solution is that if your url is:

https://qa.secure.com/somethingdev.aspx
or
https://QA.secure.com/somethingdev.aspx

it does not work as expected.

If you want to go that way you should at least chek only the [Host](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host(v=vs.110).aspx) part of the `Uri`

```
Request.Url.Host.ToLower().Contains("dev.")
```

My approach in this kind of situation is to store the login url as a config parameter on the web.config or in a custom config file or on the db

Comment: the web.config solution is what Zath suggested, and I've implemented and tested along those lines. Cheers!